# Dynamic Database Table Relation

Tags: php, database, laravel, dynamic, relationships

I am having a little problem. I guess I also have a solution but not sure if it's a clean one.

Let's say I have a website with different objects: `Person`, `Product`

Now users should be able to comment these, so I want another table for comments, but how should I tell my site whether the comment is for a person or product?

My solution: It would be a many-to-many relation, so I have a pivot table for the IDs. It would look like:

```
id
person_id
product_id
```

When the comment is for a person I would set the `person_id`, and set the `product_id` to `NULL`... if it's a product i would set `person_id` to `NULL`.

Would that be a good way to do it? Are there any best practices for this kind of issue?

Comment: The term you're looking for is *Polymorphic Relationships* Take a look at [this part of the Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#polymorphic-relations) to see how it's done in Eloquent

Comment: ohh I didn't know what to look for, thank you!!!